# how to display components router link based on user login?

Tags: typescript, angular8

How to display  admin router links in browser when admin login and when customer logged in  replacing admin router links and displaying customer router links
i have tried in app.component.html but all the router links are displaying

Answer (score 1):

You can use router guards [canDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) or [canActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) from @angular/router.